# How to deserialize dumped BSON with arbitrarily many documents in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bson

I have a `BSON` file that comes from a `mongoexport` of a database. Let's assume the database is `todo` and the collection is `items`. Now I want to load the data offline into my RN app. Since the collection may contain arbitrarily many documents (lets say 2 currently), I want to use a method to parse the file however many documents it contains.

I have tried the following methods:

1. Use external `bsondump` executable.

We can convert the file to `JSON` using a external command

```
bsondump --outFile items.json items.bson
```

But I am developing a mobile app, so invoking a third-party executable in shell command is not ideal. Plus, the output contains **several lines of one-line JSON objects**, so the output is technically *not* a correct JSON file. So parsing afterwards is not graceful.

2. Use `deserialize` in `js-bson` library

According to the [`js-bson` documentation](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson#deserialize), we can do

```
const bson = require('bson')
const fs = require('fs')
bson.deserialize(fs.readFileSync(PATH_HERE))
```

But this raises an error

```
Error: buffer length 173 must === bson size 94
```

and by adding this option,

```
bson.deserialize(fs.readFileSync(PATH_HERE), {
    allowObjectSmallerThanBufferSize: true
})
```

the error is resolved but only returns the first document. Because the documentation doesn't mention that this function can only parse 1-document collection, I wonder if there is some option that enables multiple document reading.

3. Use `deserializeStream` in `js-bson`

```
let docs = []
bson.deserializeStream(fs.readFileSync(PATH_HERE), 0, 2, docs, 0)
```

But this methods requires a parameter of the document count (2 here).

4. Use `bson-stream` library

I am actually using `react-native-fetch-blob` instead of `fs`, and according to their documentation, the stream object does not have a `pipe` method, which is the one-and-only method demonstrated in `bson-stream` doc. So although this method does not require the number of documents, I am confused how to use it.

```
// fs
const BSONStream = require('bson-stream');
fs.createReadStream(PATH_HERE).pipe(new BSONStream()).on('data', callback);

// RNFetchBlob
const RNFetchBlob = require('react-native-fetch-blob');
RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream(PATH_HERE, ENCODING)
.then(stream => {
    stream.open();
    stream.can_we_pipe_here(new BSONStream())
    stream.onData(callback)
});
```

Also I'm not sure about the above `ENCODING` above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have read the source code of `js-bson` and has figured out a way to solve the problem. I think it's better to keep a detailed record here:

## Approach 1

Split documents by ourselves, and feed the documents to parser one-by-one.

### BSON internal format

Let's say the `.json` dump of our `todo/items.bson` is

```
{_id: "someid#1", content: "Launch a manned rocket to the sun"}
{_id: "someid#2", content: "Wash my underwear"}
```

Which clearly *violates* the JSON syntax because there isn't an outer object wrapping things together.

> EDIT: I later encountered the term "JSON stream", which seems to describe such a format. This term is used by `jq` (the command line tool for JSON manipulation), although the term may indicate that those JSON documents are intended to come one-by-one in a stream.

The internal BSON is of similar shape, but it seems BSON *allows* this kind of multi-object stuffing in one file.

Then for each document, the four leading bytes indicates the length of this document, including this prefix itself and the suffix. The suffix is simply a 0 byte.

The final BSON file resembles

```
LLLLDDDDDDD0LLLLDDD0LLLLDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD0...
```

where `L` is length, `D` is binary data, `0` is literally 0.

### The algorithm

Therefore, we can develop a simple algorithm to get the document length, do the `bson.deserialize` with `allowObjectSmallerThanBufferSize` which will get a first document from buffer start, then slice off this document and repeat.

### About encoding

One extra thing I mentioned is encoding in the React Native context. The libraries dealing with React Native persistent seems to all lack the support of reading the *raw buffer* from a file. The closest choice we have is `base64`, which is a string representation of *any* binary file. Then we use `Buffer` to convert `base64` strings to buffers and feed into the algorithm above.

### The code

deserialize.js

```js
const BSON = require('bson');

function _getNextObjectSize(buffer) {
    // this is how BSON 
    return buffer[0] | (buffer[1] << 8) | (buffer[2] << 16) | (buffer[3] << 24);
}

function deserialize(buffer, options) {
    let _buffer = buffer;
    let _result = [];

    while (_buffer.length > 0) {
        let nextSize = _getNextObjectSize(_buffer);
        if (_buffer.length < nextSize) {
            throw new Error("Corrupted BSON file: the last object is incomplete.");
        }
        else if (_buffer[nextSize - 1] !== 0) {
            throw new Error(`Corrupted BSON file: the ${_result.length + 1}-th object does not end with 0.`);
        }

        let obj = BSON.deserialize(_buffer, {
            ...options,
            allowObjectSmallerThanBufferSize: true,
            promoteBuffers: true // Since BSON support raw buffer as data type, this config allows
            // these buffers as is, which is valid in JS object but not in JSON
        });
        _result.push(obj);
        _buffer = _buffer.slice(nextSize);
    }

    return _result;
}

module.exports = deserialize;
```

App.js

```js
import RNFetchBlob from `rn-fetch-blob`;
const deserialize = require('./deserialize.js');
const Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer;

RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile('...', 'base64')
    .then(b64Data => Buffer.from(b64Data, 'base64'))
    .then(bufferData => deserialize(bufferData))
    .then(jsData => {/* Do anything here */})
```

## Approach 2

The above method reads the files as a whole. Sometimes when we have a very large `.bson` file, the app may crash. Of course one can change the `readFile` to `readStream` above and add various checks to determine if the current chunk contains an ending of a document. This can be troublesome, and we are actually re-writing the `bson-stream` library!

So instead, we can create a `RNFetchBlob` file stream, and another `bson-stream` parsing stream. This *brings us back to the attempt #4* in the question.

After reading the source code, **the BSON parsing stream is inherited form a node.js Transform string**. Instead of `piping`, we can manually forward chunks and events from `onData` and `onEnd` to `on('data')` and `on('end')`.

Since **`bson-stream` does not support passing options to underlying `bson` library calls**, one may want to tweak the library source code a little in their own projects.